# React Native localeCompare not working on Android

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying sort my array alphabetically.

```
myArray.sort(function(a, b){
    return a.title.localeCompare(b.title ,'tr');
  })
```

myArray includes turkish characters like 'ç,ş,ü,ö,ı'. My code works correctly on ios but it doesn't work the way i want it on android. It sort alphabatically but words starting with turkish characters are at the bottom of list.

Answer (score 6):

In recent versions of React Native, you can enable Intl support in your Android app by changing the value of `jscFlavor` in `app/build.gradle` to `org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+`

[The location to change the value in the gradle file](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/5ddf00ee1acbf66c7204227c398a58c13e4545cf/template/android/app/build.gradle#L112)

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue with latest RN `0.61.5` on Android.

I ended up using [lodash deburr](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#deburr) to remove accented chars from my strings and I then call `String.localCompare` on deburred strings. It seems to do the job so far...